# accessing array in array in mustache PHP

Tags: php, mustache

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[attributes] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Fysieke eigenschappen
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Materiaal
                                [value] => Metaal
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Prijsklasse
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Prijsklasse
                                [value] => € 751 - € 1000
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => Opslagruimte
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Opslagruimte uitbreidbaar
                                [value] => y
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

And the mustache code:

```
{{# attributes }}

    {{ name }}

    {{# attributes }}

        {{ name }}: {{ value }}

    {{/ attributes }}

{{/ attributes }}
```

As you can see, I want to loop through each subarray in the array attributes, and then loop again. This does not work in mustache, but is there a workaround possible?

Comment: you should need to write {{name}} : {{value}}

Comment: looks like your main(outer) `attributes` array is associative array. Will you how your real php array instead if `print_r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this use

```
{{ item.attributes.name }}: {{ item.attributes.value }}
```

Use This.

```
{{ name }}: {{ value }}
```

Comment: does not work, I changed my question because it was not the correct array. Can you please check my question again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Directly put name in loop

```
{{ item.id }}: {{ item.name }} // this works!
{{# item.attributes }}
    {{ name }}: {{ value }} // try this
{{/ item.attributes }}
```

Comment: does not work, I changed my question because it was not the correct array. Can you please check my question again?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should look like this:

```
{
    'attributes': [
        {
            'name': 'Fysieke eigenschappen',
            'attributes': [
                {
                    'name':'Materiaal',
                    'value': 'Metaal'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Prijsklasse',
            'attributes': [
                {
                    'name':'Prijsklasse',
                    'value': '€ 751 - € 1000'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Opslagruimte',
            'attributes': [
                {
                    'name':'Opslagruimte uitbreidbaar',
                    'value': 'y'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

then your template will work...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2uwa9q8n/1/)